# Increase variable in render ( ) and remove the Rectangle and Image

Tags: java, libgdx, render, collision

I would like to raise a variable coin during any overlaps .
The problem is that the coin is an image and can not increase it only once , in making me the coin increases at least 10/11 times .
My goal is to remove the picture and then also the rectangle , as I did in the code below . The problem is that if I remove the Rectangle then I do not even recognize the overlaps on coins . How can I fix ?

```
render()
....
    if(!monetaRectangles.isEmpty() && !monetaImages.isEmpty()) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < monetaRectangles.size(); i++) {
                            monetaRectangles.get(i).setX(monetaImages.get(i).getX());
                            monetaRectangles.get(i).setY(monetaImages.get(i).getY());

                            if (surferRectangle.overlaps(monetaRectangles.get(i))) {
                                contatoreMonete++;
                                monetaRectangles.remove(i);
                                monetaImages.get(i).remove();
                                moneteLabel.setText("Monete: " + contatoreMonete);
                            }
                        }
                    }
...
end render()
```

the duration dell'overlaps object is one second , so I increased the variable to each render correctly , you might like to solve ? I am short on logic

Comment: Store removed rectangle on another list?

Comment: no i don't store rectangle in another list

Comment: I am suggesting this technique to you.

Comment: ah I understand only now , currently the coins are already in another list , which is what you see in the body of the request .

Answer (score 0):

You are doing modification of the collection while iterating over it. (Use libGDX collections so that new Iterator is not created every time)

```
for (int i = 0; i < monetaRectangles.size(); i++) { //
    monetaRectangles.get(i).setX(monetaImages.get(i).getX());// if you removed 'i' in the previous loop this will effectively get i+2 of the original
    monetaRectangles.get(i).setY(monetaImages.get(i).getY());

    if (surferRectangle.overlaps(monetaRectangles.get(i))) {
        contatoreMonete++;
        monetaRectangles.remove(i); //The semantics of 'i' is now changed.
        monetaImages.get(i).remove();//also here
        moneteLabel.setText("Monete: " + contatoreMonete);
    }
}
```

Use an iterator over a collection of objects that preserves the relationship between your image and your rectangle. then you can do Iterator.remove(), and carry on iterating correctly.

Some general advice - it seems that you are trying to keep the 'position' of your physics/gameworld in sync with the 'position' of your image, or vice versa.

I would suggest re-architecturing your game objects to be compositions of "rendering data", "physics/world data" and "game logic data/processes". Then, centralize common attributes in components that are accessible by both. Position is a common candidate for this kind of data. Now, when you update the position, everything that uses that position is also updated.

Ashley is a LibGDX project that helps with this, and it points at this article to explain it: [entity systems](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013)